# Hyperlink tappable area get disturbed in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview

I am using UITextView to show following text:

```
txtTest.userInteractionEnabled = true;
txtTest.selectable = true
txtTest.dataDetectorTypes = .Link;
txtTest.text = "<p>لتيتنظربهاإلىالأمورتؤثربنجاحكفيالعملفعلًاأتعرفالقولالمأثورالقديملاتنظرللنصفالفارغمنالكأسوالطريقةالتيتنظربهاإلىالأمورتؤثربنجاحكفيالعملفعلًا</p><a href=\"https://google.com\" target=\"_blank\">رابط خارجي external link</a>"
```

`UITextView` link is not tappable on text `رابط خارجي external link`. Tappable area goes somewhere else in the `UITextView`. I just figured out it by tapping random locations on `UITextView`

Don't know is it the bug of UITextView or something is missing from my side. If anyone experienced the same issue and found any solution?

Comment: Instead of giving negative votes, you can suggest me to update question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make your `UIViewController` confirm to `UITextViewDelegate` protocol and implement textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:). your standard `UITextView` setup should look something like this, don't forget the `delegate` and `dataDetectorTypes`.

```
txtTest.delegate = self
txtTest.isUserInteractionEnabled = true // default: true
txtTest.isEditable = false // default: true
txtTest.isSelectable = true // default: true
txtTest.dataDetectorTypes = [.link]
```

`UITextViewDelegate` method `shouldInteractWithURL`:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    print("Link Selected!")
    return true
}
```

and instead of using anchor tag use `attributedText` to detect link in your selected text in swift way.

```
    let targetLink = "https://google.com"

    let yourAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]
    let yourOtherAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)]

    let partOne = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "لتيتنظربهاإلىالأمورتؤثربنجاحكفيالعملفعلًاأتعرفالقولالمأثورالقديملاتنظرللنصفالفارغمنالكأسوالطريقةالتيتنظربهاإلىالأمورتؤثربنجاحكفيالعملفعلً ", attributes: yourAttributes)
    let partTwo = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " رابط خارجي external link", attributes: yourOtherAttributes)
    let text = " رابط خارجي external link"
    let str = NSString(string: text)
    let theRange = str.range(of: text)
    partTwo.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: targetLink, range: theRange)

    let combination = NSMutableAttributedString()

    combination.append(partOne)
    combination.append(partTwo)
    txtTest.attributedText = combination
```

if you want to use HTML then you still have to convert it to `NSAttributedString`. This function will convert all the HTML tags into `NSAttributedString`.

```
extension String{
    func convertHtml() -> NSAttributedString{
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do{
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        }catch{
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use it like so.

```
let stringValue = "<p>لتيتنظربهاإلىالأمورتؤثربنجاحكفيالعملفعلًاأتعرفالقولالمأثورالقديملاتنظرللنصفالفارغمنالكأسوالطريقةالتيتنظربهاإلىالأمورتؤثربنجاحكفيالعملفعلًا</p><a href=\"https://google.com\" target=\"_blank\">رابط خارجي external link</a>"

txtTest.attributedText = stringValue.convertHtml()
```

Comment: Govind Kumawat! Thanks for your reply. Actually we are getting this content from server and it may have huge number of links; So it would not be appropriate to parse that html and create tappable links manually; We need any automated process. Above solution may also increase processing time.

Comment: @msmq you can't just sent html to textView and get it tappable like need to tell which text is a link, in swift way that you can do by NSAttributedString.